# Can not set hidden field of form

Tags: javascript, forms, hidden, ecmascript-5

I am trying to set an `input` of type `hidden` in a form before submitting it and i do not understand why it does not set my field:

**HTML**

```
    <form id="createForm" method="post" action="[myhost]/[myaddress]/[mypath]" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      <input type="hidden" id="ticket" name="Ticket" />
    </form>

   <input id="setterInput" type="text"/>
   <button onclick="methods.setHidden()"></button>
```

**JS**

```
window.methods = {
    setHidden: function () {
            var form = document.getElementById('createForm');
            var setter=document.getElementById('setter');
            var input = document.getElementsByName('Ticket');
            input.value = setter.value;
            console.log(input.value); //has the desired value
      //looking with the debugger in my form at the target input, the value is still default
    }

}
```

When i set the debugger in the `console.log` line the `input` variable is set.But it does not get reflected in the `form`.
When i scroll through the form the value of the `input` is still "".

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of elements, even if there is just one element.

You could do two things:

Change this:

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('Ticket');
```

to this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('ticket');
```

Or if you wanted to keep using `getElementsByName`, you could access its value like this:

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('Ticket')[0];
```

Comment: It did the trick , changing from accessing it by `id` and not by `name` even though even in the initial case , the object was not `null`.

Answer (score 2):

In case you choose to use "getElementsByName", remember that it is plural(get*Elements*ByName) and so it will return us an array list of node elements. So this way of accessing the array element can help   `var input = document.getElementsByName('Ticket')[0];`